# What is the correct usage of replace by regex in Angular4 Template?

Tags: angular

I have a requirement of masking SSN. So, I did the following changes:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.ssn.length != 4">
  {{ user.ssn ? user.ssn.replace(/[0-9]{3}-{0,1}[0-9]{2}/, "#") : null }}
</ng-container>
```

but replace by regular expression throws me exception:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token
>   / at column 62 in [
>                     {{ user.ssn ? user.ssn.replace(/[0-9]{3}-{0,1}[0-9]{2}/, "#") : null }}

If I use a strinf instead of regex, I don't get any errors. But, as it's not possible to determine exactly what to replace, I needed to use regex.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Move the regex to TypeScript and use bindings. Your approach is a bad idea anyway, because `replace()` will be called every time change detection is run. A better approach would be to assign the result of `replace(...)` to a property in the component and bind to that property instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ok, Will try that suggestion. But, still out of curiosity, I would like to know the correct syntax. Thank You

Comment: I guess there is none. I assume raw regex isn't supported in binding expressions. Binding expression syntax isn't full JS or full TS. For example you couldn't do `new RegExp('[0-9]...')` as a workaround because types can't be used in expressions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Okay, Thank You